# Scrapy installation problems related to OS architecture

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to install scrapy in windows 7 64 bit OS. I followed the installation procedure which is mentioned in scrapy website. After installation for verification purpose when i tried to see scrapy version it gave me an weird error. I searched it, i installed all scrapy dependencies of 64 bit only.

Please find the error screenshot below.[image]

Comment: Try to uninstall lxml, then install it using this binary package https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/l/lxml/lxml-3.2.1.win-amd64-py2.7.exe#md5=f981319fb3a0d7e2aa19889081e8aa87.

Comment: Additionally, use this guide: http://steamforge.net/wiki/index.php/How_to_Install_Scrapy_in_64-bit_Windows_7

Comment: I followed the same doc and still the error coming.

Comment: From a Python interpreter, do you get the same error if you type "from lxml import etree"?